# Reverse a c-type string

Tags: c++, c-strings

Here is my code:

```
    void reverseStr(char *str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return;
    int i=0, j=strlen(str) -1;
    while(i<j)
    {
        char temp = str[j];  //i think this is the cause of the problem
        str[j] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

So here is where it is called:

```
int main()
{   
    char *str = "Forest Gump";
    reverseStr(str);
    cout << str;
}
```

Here is my error:

> /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/C.tmbundle/Support/bin/bootstrap.sh:
>   line 7:  1931 Bus error               "$3".out

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that calls `reverseStr` .

Comment: Is the string null terminated?

Comment: It looks like TextMate crashed. Why do you think *your* source code had anything to do with that? Have you tried your code with some other editor? Does your code compile with the command-line C compiler? What about via XCode?

Comment: When you've posted the calling code we'll know whether this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345584/reversing-a-string-in-c .

Comment: just a style comment, I would use a for loop instead of a while loop. Also, I think your method will break for symmetric strings. And this should probably be tagged C and not C++ or else you should just use a std::string

Comment: It would do to mention that this algorithm and the one @Charles mentions will fail globalization tests. If you're interested in details, check out http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx.

Comment: For me it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Presumably he's using textmate as an IDE to kick off his built code. bootstap.sh?

Comment: have you considered running the program in a debugger ?

Comment: When I ran this code my computer caught fire and then exploded my house :(

Comment: This is decidedly not C. C doesn't use `<<` to mean anything but left-shift.

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: I hope your insurance covers nasal demons.

Comment: My compiler (gcc 4.2) gives me a warning when I try to assign a literal to a non-const char*: "deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’". As you obviously use C++ (cout), I wonder if your compiler didn't give you that warning or if you just ignored it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse C-style String? - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197412/reverse-c-style-string-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Str pointes to a fixed string.  You are modifying it in place.  In other words, you trying to change the text literal.  Try this:

```
char *str = strdup("Forest Gump"); 
reverseStr(str); 
cout << str; 
free(str);
```

Comment: Or just `char str[] = "Forest Gump";` removing the need to memory allocation and management.

Answer (score 4):

String literals are read only memory, you can't reverse them, nor modify them in any way without encountering undefined behavior.

Copy your string into a buffer first, then pass in the buffer.  Or declare an array instead of a pointer and initialize that array with a string initializer.

Comment: No, since `i > j` in that case

Comment: @palswim: I changed my answer I realized that right after I posted it.

Comment: in fact, on Linux with gcc, it SIGSEGVs on the line str[j] = str[i]; (where i = 0 and j = 10).

Comment: Yeah, I was about to post the same "answer" right when you did before I realized that the strlen() == 0 error case wouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in a bash/shell script not in your program. Would you please post the bash script also?